# Accidently deleted magento media - how to get back the product images?

Tags: image, magento, csv, import

I accidentally deleted some part of the /media folder on my magento installation on the server. I had imported the products with images using standard magento CSV import, now they are deleted for all products!

Please suggest a way to get the images back. I have all the images with me but magento places them in differently named folders, so i cannot upload them into one place...

Is it possible to change the configuration of magento to get all the product images from the same folder?

Also, I have the CSV with image paths pointing to /media/import but I'll have to run the CSV again and there a chance of losing existing product data in that.

Any useful advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: In future a Magento application backup is a good idea as you could just untar the specific folder and be back into operation as the image paths are still in place in the database, just no images present. Putting the images back = instant recovery. Running an e-commerce site without a backup plan (even in the development stages) is a plan for failure. (added as comment because getting the images back will involve reimport and so is not a solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to upload and re-import the images.